# Blackberry 10 image upload

Tags: image, blackberry-10

I am getting this error when trying to upload image Process 1780056901 (Zain) terminated SIGSEGV code=1 fltno=11 ip=00000000. I am getting no help from blackberry forums, and most of blackberry documention is next to trash..and so many codes they have put are flat out wrong documentation and dont work.

```
void ApplicationUI::getPicture()
{
FilePicker* filePicker = new FilePicker();
filePicker->setType(FileType::Picture);
filePicker->setTitle("Select Picture");
filePicker->setMode(FilePickerMode::Picker);
filePicker->open();
QObject::connect(filePicker,
        SIGNAL(fileSelected(const QStringList&)),
        this,
        SLOT(onFileSelected(const QStringList&)));

  }
      void ApplicationUI::onFileSelected(const QStringList& list) {
try
{
    QFile file (list[0]);
    ImageView* ay = root->findChild<ImageView*>("imageName");
    if(ay != NULL)
        ay->setImage(Image(list[0]));
    QString body = "" ;
    QSettings settings("Netvariant", "Zain");
    QString locale_string = settings.value("lang").toString();
    if(locale_string == "ar")
        locale_string == "ar";
    else
        locale_string = "en";
    const QUrl url("myurl");
     QHttpPart imagePart;
     imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/jpeg"));
     imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"imageFile\""));
     imagePart.setRawHeader("Content-ID", "my@content.id"); // add any headers you like via setRawHeader()
     file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
     imagePart.setBodyDevice(&file);
     QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
     file.setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart
      multiPart->append(imagePart);
      QNetworkRequest request(url);

      QNetworkAccessManager* netManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
      QNetworkReply *reply = netManager->post(request, multiPart);


}
catch(...)
{

}
 }
```

Comment: I have posted a response to your question on the BB forum, here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Process-1780056901-Zain-terminated-SIGSEGV-code-1-fltno-11-ip/td-p/2871142

Comment: You said "I am getting no help from blackberry forums".  Really?  You gave that forum 1 hour before posting here, it has been here 3 hours before you got a response.  So are you going to go on another forum and say stack overflow is useless?  And what about the questions you have already asked and had answered on the BB forum?  When did you last help anyone?  You have been on this forum 2 months and not answered a question.  And I don't see any solutions on the BB forum.  You get back what you give...